# UIView's layout margins are reset to 8 UIStackView in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

If you set explicit custom layout margins for a `UIView` that is contained in a `UIStackView`, they are reset to `8, 8, 8, 8` at runtime.

I created a demo project [here](https://github.com/revolter/StackOverflow-LayoutMarginsIgnored).

Comment: I did find you that if you enable `preserves​Superview​Layout​Margins` for the `secondView` in my demo, it works, but it makes no sense. Doesn't that means that it should take the `UIStackView`'s layout margins instead?

Comment: Well, if it puts your mind at ease... I've confirmed what you've found. Played around with the arrangements a bit, and it always follows the "loses custom margins unless preserved" behavior. It does make me wonder if the common description of `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins` is either wrong, or just very confusing / unintuitive.